# Best way to send data that will populate multiple divs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Looking for your advice!**

Im looking at a new method to update multiple  with data.

Currently, I have say 3 divs.
I then have three scripts that get called every x seconds. Each script calls an external php file and in turn then updates the div that the script is designed for.

Im wondering,
Is it possible to have a single .php server file that can get called once.
But update multiple divs with the html data?

Maybe have the .php file output something like

div1html='*HTMLCODE*';

div2html='*HTMLCODE*';

div3html='*HTMLCODE*';

( Above clearly wont work because the html may contain ' or ; or whatever anyway.. )

And then have a single script that is called once to update all 3 divs with the data from a single call? ( Rather than 3 scripts calling 3 different files for each div )

I'm just looking for your advice on the best ( and easiest ) way to achieve this?

Thanks guys. Hopefully you will come up with something for me.
-Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the data json encoded. see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->div1html = 'bla';
$data->div2html = 'more bla';
$data->div3html = 'even more bla';
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Json can easely read by javascript and will handle all escaping for you.

Comment: Ohhhhh I like...

How easy is it to read that and place it into the divs from the client side JS?

Comment: if you use a library like [jquery](http://jquery.com/) you can do something like this: `$.ajax({url:'http://myserver.com/mypage.php'}).done(function(data){ $('#div1html').html(data.div1html); })` Using native javascript you can parse the json using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Hi, Thanks..
Been at this for a few hours now and cant figure it out.
I guess I need to get the data from the file into some object/string/whatever and then have JS look for a key and fill the div based on teh key after decoding it..
I just cant figure out how :(  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh Hang on...
Im being stupid aint I?
I was trying to use "native JS" and the Jquery...
I see what you mean now.. The above code works if I use Jquery... if I didnt use Jquery.. then I would use json.parse!

It seems to work fine with just the code you posted without using the json.parse stuff!!!

Was I just being stupid?  I use jquery.. So i will just use `$.ajax({url:'http://myserver.com/mypage.php'}).done(function(data){ $('#div1html').html(data.div1html); }) `wont i?